# postgresql - como enviar un parametro tabla en una funcion?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estoy utilizando postgresql, quisiera saber como enviar un parametro tabla en una funcion.

ya he creado el type type_detalle_ac :

```
CREATE TYPE public.type_detalle_ac AS
(
id_componente integer,
precio numeric(10,2),
cantidad integer,
sub_total numeric(10,2)
);
```

y lo utilizo en la siguiente funcion :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.sp_adm_artefacto(
v_serie character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
v_tipo_artefacto integer DEFAULT NULL::integer,
v_modelo character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
v_marca integer DEFAULT NULL::integer,
v_detalle type_detalle_ac DEFAULT NULL::type_detalle_ac,
v_usuario integer DEFAULT NULL::integer,
v_id_artefacto integer DEFAULT NULL::integer,
v_tipo_operacion character DEFAULT NULL::bpchar)
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

COST 100
VOLATILE 
ROWS 0
AS $BODY$

DECLARE 

    VL_ID_ARTEFACTO INTEGER;
BEGIN
    IF V_TIPO_OPERACION = 'I' THEN

        INSERT INTO DETALLE_AC(ID_DETALLE_AC,ID_ARTEFACTO,ID_COMPONENTE,PRECIO,CANTIDAD,SUB_TOTAL,
                               USUARIO_CREACION,FECHA_CREACION)
        SELECT 1,1,ID_COMPONENTE,PRECIO,CANTIDAD,SUB_TOTAL,v_usuario,NOW() FROM V_DETALLE;

    END IF;

END;


$BODY$;
```

Pero al llamar la funcion :

```
SELECT "sp_adm_artefacto"('1321321',1,'F-14',1,(1,10,5,50),1,NULL,'I')
```

pero me sale un error :

```
ERROR:  no existe la relación «v_detalle»
LINE 3: ...NTE,PRECIO,CANTIDAD,SUB_TOTAL,v_usuario,NOW() FROM V_DETALLE
```

gracias

Comment: Un lío está en que le estés dando RETURNS void, siendo que el RETURN debe especificar el uso del TYPE que declaraste

Answer (score -1):

Para pasar una tabla como parámetro  a una función debes usar **TYPE** para definir tu tabla como un nuevo **tipo de dato**. Lee la  documentación [Aqui](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createtype.html)

Comment: Hola he editado la pregunta poniendole mas informacion, ya he probado TYPE, pero me sale un error

Comment: ¿Porque pones la linea public.type_detalle_ac ? Deberia ser solo type_detalle_ac

Comment: es lo que me sale cuando saco el script de type_detalle_ac

Comment: Viendo mejor tu código  y lo que intentas hacer. ¿No es mejor pasar las 4 variables como parámetros en vez de  declarar un TYPE?

Comment: Hola, no lo creo, ya que después quiero enviar una tabla

Comment: Las respuestas que son sólo un enlace, suelen ser muy escuetas para resolver las preguntas y suelen perder validez con el tiempo, una vez los enlaces se rompen. Procura añadir los datos relevantes a la respuesta, incluyendo el código de ejemplo que consideres útil